# How would I format a CD RW disk for FAT32?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Are there any free burners that I can download that would enable me to format a CD-RW disc for the FAT system on Vista?

Thank you from

Mr Berwyn H Price (I live in Scotland)

I thank everyone for their replies. Also I would like to take this opportunity to explain further what my question "Are there any free burners that I can download that would enable me to format a CD-RW disc for the FAT system on Vista?" means.

Have a small tower computer that has Windows 98 SE installed which I want to sell with the installation disc, product key, software and 2 books, to someone who want to learn about 'modern' computing. If cannot sell I will give away free!

Did install update drivers for motherboard (Intel Whitney SR Board - either Pentium 2 or 3) and for the CRT monitor (Compaq S510).

The reason why I state "Did" at the beginning of the above sentence is because I have to start again by re-installing the above mentioned drivers because of a problem that I encountered.

But there is a problem with that before I even start: Windows 98 SE will not except a USB flash drive when it has in the past and the CD-RW ReWritable High Speed drive will not read a CD-RW disc when it has in the past!

Have 2 USB flash drives (iFlash 8GB and PNY 8GB). Also, the laptop I use has an inbuilt DVD-RW drive (Compact Disc ReWritable Ultra Speed, DVD Multi-Recorder and RW DVD+ReWritable) that I use to write onto CD-RW disc with no problems.

So, because of that problem I realised that any USB flash drive or CD-RW disc that I use might, or would, have to be formatted in the FAT system to enable me to use it in the Windows 98 SE computer. Seems strange because I have never had this problem in the past!

Hope that explanation makes it clearer and I hope that someone can advise me and, maybe, provide a link or suggestion.

Thank you from

Mr Berwyn H Price

Hi Vinayak

About 47 minutes ago, at about 1.30pm (it's now 2.16pm in Scotland) I formatted the iFlash USB flash drive to enable me to place the drivers for the motherboard (Intel Whitney SR Board - either Pentium 2 or 3), an .exe that contains the driver and INF file for the CRT monitor (Compaq S510), and other needed drivers and .exes for the small tower computer, that has Windows 98 SE installed.

I used a very well known program to format said mentioned flash drive 3 times for 3 recognised file systems (FAT, FAT32 and UDF). (The program creates a partition on the flash drive of or for the chosen file system).

But when I placed the flash drive into the usb port 3 times Windows 98 SE did not recognise or read it!

So, it's 'back to the drawing board'. Also, I do have 3 questions: 1. Do I try another or different  flash drive?; Or 2. Do I burn what I need onto a CD-RW disc using a program such as InCD?

What I would really like is a program similar to the one that I used mentioned above that would create a partition on a CD-RW disc of or for a chosen file system!

Can you please advise, suggest anything or maybe provide al link. Would be very grateful if you do.

Thank you for your trouble in this matter and I do look forward to receiving a reply from you soon on this website in the near future.

From

Mr Berwyn H Price

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here. You can try the [Software Reqs SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Are you trying to format a CD as FAT?

Comment: I wonder if we could re-format the question to better fit SU(How would I, rather than "where do I get a tool?"), rather than suggest a migration - considering that the answer is probably no, and its a result of the limitations of the physical medium. I've made a bit of an edit, but saying *why* you're trying to do what you're doing may help improve the question massively. I'd also add that you don't need to sign off, and mention where you're from. Stick to the technical aspects in your question.

Comment: It's not actually a FAT32 filesystem, but Nero InCD allows access to a CD-RW as if it's a flopply disk.

Comment: I don't know how you made the assumption that burning a CD-RW with a FAT32 filesystem (if it were possible) would help you access the contents of it. If you need to install device drivers and can access your USB drives on your Win98 computer (assuming they were formatted as FAT32) then why not just copy the device drivers from the CD to the USB drive using another computer, stick the flash drive into the Win98 PC and install the drivers?

Answer (score 3):

You *typically* cannot format a CD RW disk to fat32. Fat32 is designed for *hard drives*. They're media that are typically written to, and read fairly often. The filesystems for use are designed for the stratergies disks use (DAO - where the whole disk is written to at once, TAO, where a whole track is written to, and packet data, where data is *appended* as packets). You can erase a *whole* cd rw, but not selective bits of data, so FAT32 makes no sense.

The only optical media that you *might* be able to store a FAT32 filesystem on is [DVD RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_RAM)